# Translation of prompt boxes

Tags: localisation

I want to translate the text in prompt boxes on my magento shop (CE 1.9), but can't seem to find the location(s) / file(s) in which I can change it. I've searched in the locale folder and various phmtl-files but with no luck. Some of the prompt boxes I want to change:

1. In the Cart, confirmation that you want to remove item from shopping cart.
2. On the (configurable) product page, not having selected a variant of the product when clicking the 'add to cart' button.

Can someone point me in the right direction where the files that need to be modified are on the server?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your text using the translator function see `Translator. translate ( 'Some string' )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to locate the codes which display the prompt boxes. Instead just add your translations in

> app/design/frontend/PACKAGE/THEME/locale/LANGUAGE/translate.csv

.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. WHen looking for it I found out that an extension in my cart retrieves its translation-data elsewhere altogether and that's where I needed to change it.